# How to write UDF with values as references to other columns?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I'd like to create a UDF that does the following:

A `DataFrame`has 5 columns and with want to create the 6th column with the sum that the value that contain the name the first and the second column.

Let me print the `DataFrame` and explain with that:

```
case class salary(c1: String, c2: String, c3: Int, c4: Int, c5: Int)

val df = Seq(
    salary("c3", "c4", 7, 5, 6),
    salary("c5", "c4", 8, 10, 20),
    salary("c5", "c3", 1, 4, 9))
    .toDF()
```

`DataFrame` result

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
| c1| c2| c3| c4| c5|
+---+---+---+---+---+
| c3| c4|  7|  5|  6|
| c5| c4|  8| 10| 20|
| c5| c3|  1|  4|  9|
+---+---+---+---+---+

df.withColumn("c6",UDFName(c1,c2))
```

And the result for this column should be:

1º Row(C3,C4) Then 7+5= 12

2º Row(C5,C4) Then 20+10= 30

3º Row(C5,C3) Then 9+1= 10

Answer (score 3):

There is really no need for UDF here. Just use virtual `MapType` column:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, lit, map}

// We use an interleaved list of column name and column value
val values = map(Seq("c3", "c4", "c5").flatMap(c => Seq(lit(c), col(c))): _*)

// Check the first row
df.select(values).limit(1).show(false)
```

```
+------------------------------+
|map(c3, c3, c4, c4, c5, c5)   |
+------------------------------+
|Map(c3 -> 7, c4 -> 5, c5 -> 6)|
+------------------------------+
```

and use it in expression:

```
df.withColumn("c6", values($"c1") + values($"c2"))
```

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| c1| c2| c3| c4| c5| c6|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| c3| c4|  7|  5|  6| 12|
| c5| c4|  8| 10| 20| 30|
| c5| c3|  1|  4|  9| 10|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

It is much cleaner, faster, and safer than dealing with `UDFs` and `Rows`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{struct, udf}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val f = udf((row: Row) => for {
  // Use Options to avoid problems with null columns
  // Explicit null checks should be faster, but much more verbose
  c1 <- Option(row.getAs[String]("c1"))
  c2 <- Option(row.getAs[String]("c2"))

  // In this case we could (probably) skip Options below
  // but Ints in Spark SQL can get null
  x <- Option(row.getAs[Int](c1))
  y <- Option(row.getAs[Int](c2))
} yield x + y)

df.withColumn("c6", f(struct(df.columns map col: _*)))
```

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| c1| c2| c3| c4| c5| c6|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| c3| c4|  7|  5|  6| 12|
| c5| c4|  8| 10| 20| 30|
| c5| c3|  1|  4|  9| 10|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 1):

A user-defined function (UDF) has access to the values that are passed directly as input parameters.

If you want to access the other columns, a UDF will only have access to them *iff* you pass them as input parameters. With that, you should easily achieve what you're after.

I highly recommend using [struct](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@struct(cols:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) function to combine all the other columns.

> **struct(cols: Column*): Column** Creates a new struct column.

You could also use [Dataset.columns](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@columns:Array[String]) method to access the columns to `struct`.

> **columns: Array[String]** Returns all column names as an array.